# Static Vs Public variables in multiuser environment

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm using following approach to keep global variables in a separate class file so that they can be passed among few back-end classes. The problem is it's failing when the system is used in a multi-user environment. I can't opt for the "Session" approach, because admins are not ready to enable Session state on SharePoint server.

```
static class Global
{
        private static string id = string.Empty;
        public static string id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
}
```

If I remove the static declaration from above code, will it work properly in a multi-user scenario? What other options do I have without asking for any help from server admins.

Comment: check sppersistedobject maybe this can help a bit

Comment: @MichalFranc, `SPPersistedObject` is not going to help in per-request/per-user data as it is designed to store "administration objects" - Farm wide entities that user can't write to.

Comment: you are right Alexei :)

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `static` for things that are per-user or per-request; `static` is pretty rare in a web application, but might occasionally be used for things like keeping a snapshot of the overall system configuration (preferably immutable).

So: where can we store things?

Session-state would be the obvious answer for something that is (and here's the clue) *per session*, but it sounds like that is not an option

Beyond that, you have basically: the http request. That means you have access to the form, the query string, and the cookies. And *that's it*. You don't want to store much in the cookies: it bloats every request. And "viewstate" is just evil. If regular session-state isn't viable, you could do some home-brew "session" implementation based on some cookie (suitably secured), but frankly I think you'd do well to either:

- use the request form / query-string if all you want is an `id`
- else push your admins to get session-state enabled

Comment: Thanks Marc, I can't go with Cookie approach because I can't trust user's workstation they may have cookie disable.User may use my app from home so cookie is also out of question.

Comment: @Rishi one way or another, they need some kind of identifier. Without that, you're completely doomed.

Comment: +1. In SharePoint one can also try to save "per authenticated user" information in some list on the site...

Comment: Someone suggested me to look into PropertyBag solution in SharePoint 2010. But I guess that's also not fully reliable in multiuser approach ?

Comment: Agree @AlexeiLevenkov, But my app is already distributing data into 4-5 lists and I can't think about adding one more list :(

Answer (score 5):

Your static variables will be shared between *all users*, and will not belong to a specific user. Using static variables to keep state in a web environment is almost always a bad idea.

If you can't enable session state, a good strategy would be to:

- Add a user specific identifier to the URL, and keep that in the URL
- Save your state on the server in a database, based on that id

This way you are essentially re-inventing session state; but you avoid enabling Session state globally. If the state is sufficiently small, you could also encode it into the URL.

Also consider that Session state does not work well in a server farm environment, unless you store it on a shared server - this might be the reason your admins are not inclined to enable it.

Comment: Thanks Driis, Yup when app start showing weird stuffs I came to know Static is messing up. But now problem is what should I opt if server admins are not ready to enable Session on server.

Answer (score 3):

Statics are potentially even worse in web farm or web garden environment, which SharePoint supports quite well. Static fields are *per-AppDomain*. This means, for instance, they will be the same for all users within one worker process within one machine, but will be different between worker processes, and between machines.

Don't use statics in a multi-user application, and you won't have to worry about changes in behavior as the environment changes.

Comment: That means if I remove "Static" keyword from my above code everything should be working well in multi-user environment ?

Comment: It will "work" in the sense that it won't be getting shared across multiple users.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Is it the same case, with readonly public static variables which don't change ever.

Comment: Yes. It's the "static" part that matters. You could initialize a readonly static field with, for instance, the AppDomain ID, and it would be different in each AppDomain.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need session state, get session state enabled. It's as simple as that.

However, if all you need are just a few (lightweight) session variables, you could get away with using cookies, and transfer the data back and forth on each request.

You could also try to "reimplement" a session state using something like:

```
static class Globals
{
   private static Dictionary<string, MySessionObjectType> sessions;

   public static MySessionObjectType GetSessionData(string SessionID){...}

   public static void SetSessionData
                         (string SessionID, MySessionObjectType sessionData){...}
}
```

This will, of course, not scale to multiple web-servers, and managing session time-out will be a PITA.

Don't forget that the nature of the web itself is stateless, so using too much state (whether on the server or on the client) is not always a smart choice.

Comment: Also don't forget proper synchronization in the implementation, the Dictionary is not thread safe.

Comment: @driis Yes, both the `Get` and `Set` methods should have proper synchronization, and that is very hard to get right, and can be a source of hard-to-trace bugs. @OP By all means, either avoid using session, or use the provided session, that already does all that stuff for you.